# What are the major changes in Dark Heresy 2nd edition vs. 1st edition?

Tags: warhammer-40k, edition-comparison, dark-heresy-2e, dark-heresy-1e

Dark Heresy 2nd edition has recently been released.  What are the major changes in 2nd edition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just received the book today. Based on one of the Betas I downloaded, I was expecting something drastically different and not compatible with the other 40k games. Apparently, they caved to pressure on the final product. Everything is pretty much identical to Only War. This is both good and bad. Good, because compatibility. But I was really looking forward to the "every wound is a crit" damage system and some other changes in the earlier betas.

I have to say, I'm disappointed overall. It's more like a setting now than a new game.

Comment: There are no major changes?

Comment: This is what I have heard from a friend who was following it closely.